# Is possible to pause main window in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a jquery where we do drag and drop effect based on using different images. The drag and drop works fine and we can even exchange information among the images. The issue now just before we allow the drag and drop to complete we call a pop-up window like this window.open(url, "VALUES", "width=500,height=300");. In it we have 2 text boxes and javascript to validate the data entry. The issue is that in the main window we must not proceed (drag n drop) until the pop-up window text boxes have been filled and information sent back to main window? How to control that ?

Comment: What have you tried? Can we have a minimal piece of example code that we can work with?

Comment: @ivan what I have tried so far is that I can call the pop-up window and there after the drag and drop work after calling the pop-up window I need to prevent that and I cant find anything on google on that too.

Comment: @ivan is it using modal will solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `var returnValue = window.showModalDialog(...);` instead of `window.open()`.

A modal window is a blocking call and the javascript in the main page will not proceed until the modal is closed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.showModalDialog

Comment: it works fine in Chrome the pop-up opens but not in firefox and it show this error NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIDOMWindow.showModalDialog][Break On This Error]  
...= window.showModalDialog(url1,a,"dialogwidth: 450; dialogheight: 300; resizable:...

Comment: I would like to learn further how if I need to send parameters in pair like serial1=1234&ns1=121&serial2=2232&ns2=222 and also to send multiple values back to the parent window? What I saw is this now window.dialogArguments and window.returnValue? How it works for multiple values?

Comment: pass an object using `{ key: value }` pairs and then access it in the modal dialog using `window.dialogArguments`

Comment: I guess is something like this link right http://geekswithblogs.net/faizanahmad/archive/2009/03/25/pass-multiple-values-to-modal-window.aspx and how about pass back the value to parent window same method works? Thank you.

Comment: @user837306 set the `window.returnValue` before closing the dialog.

Comment: I was testing the window pop-up and suddenly I notice on the main window I can still drag and drop other item. How to disable totally the main window when the window.showModalDialog is already opened?

Answer (score 2):

You can detect if a window has been closed or not by using the technique described [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/openclose.shtml):

```
function checker () {
    if (windowRef.closed)
        allowDrops = true;
    else
        setTimeout(checker, 100);
}
```

So what you would do is when you open the window, set `allowDrops` to false and call `checker()`.  Modify your drag and drop event handler so that it only works if allowDrops is `true`.